# How do I normalize the finance data sets in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have an Excel file as finance data with 300 samples (companies) in rows and 24 features in columns. I want to normalize the finance data.  How we can do this?

I would like to use Artificial Neural Networks, but before I do that I must normalize my data.

Comment: Besides the MATLAB duplicate, you say you've got data in Excel, so what does MATLAB have to do with this? Please read [ask] and How to create a [mcve], contained in the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before attempting to ask another question.

Comment: I removed your image. It's garbage and doesn't add to your question.